# Avoid Duplicate Email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, email, reminder

So while designing my workflow i stumbled upon a problem where in when ever the status as on date changes to completed it should send a mail to the user. But when i try to edit a a list item which already has Field value as completed and when i save the field it sends a mail to the user again.
so i just only want to send the mail when the status has been changed once to completed.
Not again and again.

This is my workflow where i am defining a condition as to not send the email when emailsent field has been set to yes !
could you point the problem out please ?

[image]

Comment: Im not sure about Workflows but usually in the SharePoint API you always have to call an "Update List Item" after changing something on the Item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the EmailSent a boolean field?

Also you could try to change it to this:

```
If EmailSent not equals Yes then send mail + set EmailSent to Yes
```

There really no need to update EmailSent every time the workflow fires and Status as on Date = completed

Comment: yes EmailSent is a Boolean Field.
i would try this and get back to you soon !
why do you say so?

Comment: Right now every time the workflow fires it wil chech if the field 'Status as on Date' = Completed and every time it finds that to be true it will set the field 'EmailSent' to True - even if that is already set. This will in turn create a new version of the element (provided you have enabled versioning) - also it will introduce another moving part which you don't really need anyway.

Comment: it is working perfectly but email sent is not being assigned to yes after the workflow is completed

Comment: Uhm then I guess it's not working as expected as that would mean the email is sent on every change in the item. Can you please try to share a screendump of how the workflow is configured now :)

Comment: it is working smoothly now. i am sorry i did not check it properly.
Thank you so much for the help!